# Meshgrid/lattice/matrix of an ellipse area

Tags: python, geometry, ellipse

I'm likely using the wrong terms but seeking some help.

I would like to generate an array of x,y values for a grid that sits within the perimeter of an ellipse shape.

There is code here: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/ellipse_grid/ellipse_grid.html to accomplish this in Python.

However, for my purpose the ellipses have been rotated to a certain degree. The current equation does not account for this and need some help to account for this transformation, unsure how to change the code to do this?

I've been looking into np.meshrid function as well, so if there are better ways to do this, please say.

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you be more precise about what you mean by a grid? For example do you require points of the form (x0+s*k, y0+s*l) where k and l are integers (so, if you will, an axis aligned grid) or would (x0,y0) +s*(k*u + l*v), where u and v are orthogonal unit vectors, do? If the latter you could generate a grid for an axis aligned ellipse and then rotate the grid for your rotated ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

To generate lattice points inside ellipse, we have to know where horizontal line intersects that ellipse.

Equation of zero-centered ellipse, rotated by angle Theta:

```
 x = a * Cos(t) * Cos(theta) - b * Sin(t) * Sin(theta)   
 y = a * Cos(t) * Sin(theta) + b * Sin(t) * Cos(theta)
```

To simplify calculations, we can introduce pseudoangle Fi and magnitude M (constants for given ellipse)

```
 Fi = atan2(a * Sin(theta), b * Cos(theta))
 M = Sqrt((a * Sin(theta))^2 + (b * Cos(theta))^2)
```

so

```
 y = M * Sin(Fi) * Cos(t) + M * Cos(Fi) * Sin(t)
 y/M = Sin(Fi) * Cos(t) +  Cos(Fi) * Sin(t)
 y/M = Sin(Fi + t)
```

and solution for given horizontal line at position y are

```
 Fi + t = ArcSin( y / M)
 Fi + t = Pi - ArcSin( y / M)
 t1 = ArcSin( y / M) - Fi        //note two values
 t2 = Pi - ArcSin( y / M) - Fi
```

Substitute both values of t in the first equation and get values of X for given Y, and generate one lattice point sequence

To get top and bottom coordinates, differentiate y

```
y' = M * Cos(Fi + t) = 0
th = Pi/2 - Fi
tl = -Pi/2 - Fi
```

find corresponding y's and use them as starting and ending Y-coordinates for lines.

```
import math

def ellipselattice(cx, cy, a, b, theta):
    res = []
    at = a * math.sin(theta)
    bt = b * math.cos(theta)
    Fi = math.atan2(at, bt)
    M = math.hypot(at, bt)
    ta = math.pi/2 - Fi
    tb = -math.pi/2 - Fi
    y0 = at * math.cos(ta) + bt *math.sin(ta)
    y1 = at * math.cos(tb) + bt *math.sin(tb)
    y0, y1 = math.ceil(cy + min(y0, y1)), math.floor(cy + max(y0, y1))
    for y  in range(y0, y1+1):
        t1 = math.asin(y / M) - Fi
        t2 = math.pi - math.asin(y / M) - Fi
        x1 = a * math.cos(t1) * math.cos(theta) - b* math.sin(t1) * math.sin(theta)
        x2 = a * math.cos(t2) * math.cos(theta) - b* math.sin(t2) * math.sin(theta)
        x1, x2 = math.ceil(cx + min(x1, x2)), math.floor(cx + max(x1, x2))
        line = [(x, y) for x in range(x1, x2 + 1)]
        res.append(line)
    return res

print(ellipselattice(0, 0, 4, 3, math.pi / 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Given an ellipse in the Euclidean plane in its most general form as quadratic curve in the form

```
f(x,y) = a x^2 + 2b x y + c y^2 + 2d x + 2f y + g,
```

one can compute the center `(x0,y0)` by

```
((cd-bf)/(b^2-ac), (af-bd)/(b^2-ac))
```

(see equations 19 and 20 at [Ellipse on MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html)). The length of the major axis `a_m` can be computed by equation 21 on the same page.

Now it suffices to find all grid points `(x,y)` inside the circle with center `(x0,y0)` and radius `a_m` with

```
sign(f(x,y)) = sign(f(x0,y0)).
```